# Shrinkage in a logistic regression model built from m datasets with imputed values

Tags: r, regression, missing-data, multiple-imputation, regularization

I am currently running a logistic regression model in R using a dataset where missing values were dealt with by using multiple imputation. I have some experience using the MICE package to deal with missing data, and the RMS package to build and validate logistic regression models. However, I am struggling to find a way to shrink my coefficients following boostrap validation on m imputed datasets.
Any help or suggestions? I hope I expressed myself clearly.
Much obliged